# Symbol’s function definition is void: revert-buffer

Tags: error, revert-buffer

For some reason whenever files change on disk, when I try to edit the file I get the following prompt but choosing `r`evert results in

```
<some-filename> changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h) r
Symbol’s function definition is void: revert-buffer
```

For context I built emacs inside a container because can't run `apt` on host

```
host$ docker run -ti -v ~/emacs:${HOME}/emacs -v ~/.local/bin:/emacs-bin ubuntu
container# wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-27.2.tar.gz
container# tar -xf emacs-27.2.tar.gz
container# cd emacs-27.2
container# ./configure --prefix=/home/<user>/emacs --bindir=/emacs-bin
container# make install
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with `emacs -q`? with `emacs -Q`? Are there any other messages in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: mhm it works fine with `emacs -q`

Comment: Then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you still have a question at that point, rewrite your question to reflect what it's really about.

Comment: Removing defadvice around `ask-user-about-supersession-threat` worked